# print currently selected item when item clicked

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this class using a picker from material ui.
I am not able to print the currently selected item

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider, DatePicker } from "@material-ui/pickers";
import MomentUtils from "@date-io/moment";


const styles = theme => ({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    width: 200,
  },
});


class YearPickerClass extends React.Component {
  state = {
    yearFrom: new Date(1900, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    yearTo: new Date(1950, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
  }


  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    console.log("willReceive")
    console.log(props)
  }

  handleChange = (date) => {
    console.log("date")
    console.log(date) //prints 1900 even if I select a different year

  }


  render() {
    const classes = this.props;
    var from = new Date(1900, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
    var to = new Date(1950, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);

    return (
      <form className={classes.container} noValidate>

        <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>

          <DatePicker
            key="yearFrom"
            views={["year"]}
            label="Year From"
            value={this.state.yearFrom}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            animateYearScrolling
            minDate={from}
            maxDate={to}

          />

        </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>


      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default (YearPickerClass);
```

Any idea how to get the currently selected item inside the handleChange function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you convert the date you got with moment, you will see that you actually get the new value in your handleChange function:

```
handleChange = date => {
  console.log(moment(date).format('YYYY'));
};
```

Please see it working:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/magical-snowflake-4fzgn

Comment: the initial selection is always printed, I am trying to get the newly selected object printed

Comment: I updated my answer with the code example. Please see that the value actually gets updated in the console.